# Finding the variance of this estimator

Tags: variance, estimation, inference

I'm not sure how to express the variance of this estimator. Here's the setup.

We have $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and want to estimate $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]$ where $\phi : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is some function such that $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]$ has finite mean and variance. We have iid samples $Y_1,\dots, Y_n \sim N(0,1)$.

This is the estimator proposed:

$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n\sigma}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \exp \left[-Y_i^2\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\phi(Y_i).$$

I have shown this estimator is unbiased. But I'm not sure how to express its variance. The most I can say is that since the $Y_i$ are iid, we have

$$var(\hat{\theta})=\frac{1}{n^2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} var\left(\exp \left[-Y_i^2\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\phi(Y_i)\right).$$

How can I express this further?

Comment: Please start by checking your work, because for $\sigma \ne 1$ your $\hat\theta$ doesn't look in the least unbiased!  Maybe there's a typographical error in your post?

Comment: @whuber Actually it is unbiased. I have done the calculation in a few lines. Why do you think it is not unbiased?

Comment: Because (1) I cannot demonstrate its lack of bias and (2) with simulated data it is clearly biased.

Comment: 1. Your estimator is clearly biased.  2. If you want to estimate the expected value of a function of $X$, why not just calculate the sample mean of the function of $X$?  How to get the standard error of this estimate should be obvious.

Comment: @jbowman Pardon me, sirs, for persisting in my view of the unbiasedness of my estimator. I will present a few-lined proof in answer to this question so you can view it

Comment: @whuber Pardon me, sirs, for persisting in my view of the unbiasedness of my estimator. I will present a few-lined proof in answer to this question so you can view it

Comment: @jbowman I have submitted a proof below of the unbiasedness of my estimator. Do you still think it is biased? Thank you for your attention and time considering my problem. Also calculating the sample mean of the function was another approach I considered. But my problem requires this approach.

Comment: @whuber I have submitted a proof below of the unbiasedness of my estimator. Do you still think it is biased? Thank you for your attention and time considering my problem

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4637746/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$

You can perform the similar calculation for variance by noting $\Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - (E[Y])^2$ for any random variable $Y$:
\begin{align}
& E\left[\exp \left[-2Y_i^2\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\phi(Y_i)^2\right] \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left[ -y^2\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}-1\right)\right]\phi(y)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-y^2/2)dy \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(y)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-y^2\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} - \frac{1}{2}\right)\right)dy
\end{align}

Now here comes the problem, **this integral diverges if $\sigma^2 > 2$**. If $\sigma^2 \leq 2$, then you can further simplify by making a change of variable of $y$ to match the standard normal density $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: Thank you @Zhanxiong. Is there a weaker condition if we know that $\int_\infty^\infty \phi(x)^2 \, dx<\infty$?

Comment: Won't work: for example, if $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{4}$, then the dominant part of the integrand is $e^{y^2/2}$.  $\phi(y) = 1/y^2$ satisfies $\int \phi(x)^2dx < \infty$ but the original integral is still divergent.

Comment: Do you mean if $\sigma^2=4$?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: I see. Also, how does $\phi(y)=1/y^2$ satisfy $\int \phi(x)^2 \, dx <\infty$? It diverges, no?

Comment: oh, typo again, i was paying attention to infinity only. You can easily modify it around $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n\sigma}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \exp \left[-Y_i^2\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\phi(Y_i)\right]$$

$$ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{\sigma}\exp \left[-Y_i^2\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\phi(Y_i)\right]$$

Now, consider the expectation above. We have

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{\sigma}\exp \left[-Y_i^2\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\phi(Y_i)\right] = \int_\infty^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma}\exp\left[ -y^2\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\phi(y) \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-y^2/2) \, dy$$

$$= \int_\infty^\infty \phi(y) \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y}{\sigma}\right)^2\right) \, dy$$

$$ = \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]$$ QED

Comment: How do you get from the next-to-last line to the last line, given that $Y$ is not in fact distributed $N(0, \sigma^2)$?

Comment: @jbowman $y$ in the integration is a dummy variable!

Comment: ... which fails to address the point.   You are integrating $\phi(y)$ with respect to a density function which is not the actual distribution of $y$, so you won't get the expected value of $\phi(y)$ out (unless, as @whuber pointed out, $\sigma = 1$.)  You will get the expected value when $Y \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, but you have already specified that $Y \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: @jbowman $\phi$ is just a function on $\mathbb{R}$. We don't integrate "wrt a density function", we integrate wrt a real variable traversing $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: 1. Yes we do, actually:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380785/what-does-it-mean-to-integrate-with-respect-to-the-distribution-function may get you started on this more advanced approach!   2. $\mathbb{E}\phi(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(y)f(y)dy$, where $f(y)$ is the probability density function of $y$.  Where is that probability density, the $N(0,1)$ specified above, in your next-to-last equation?

Comment: @jbowman I think his reasoning is correct because $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.  It will be clearer if you read backwards.

Comment: Try a simulation with $X \sim N(0,\sigma=100)$ and `theta <- function(x) ifelse(x < -100, 1, 0)`; this has an expected value of roughly 0.159 (it's just the probability of the r.v. being more than 1 std. dev. below the mean) but you will get zero out as the expectation, because $Y$ has essentially zero probability of being less than $-100$.  $X$ is not $Y$, that's the root of the problem.

Comment: @jbowman I don't quite follow your example.  But isn't $E[\phi(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(y)f_X(y)dy$, where $f_X(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ (as a result of $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$) correct? He is computing $E[\phi(X)]$, not $E[\phi(Y)]$.